# Projection is not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, resampling

I'm new to Google Earth Engine, just get started to learn how to load and process the Sentinel imagery on GEE.

Today I wanted to resample the imagery downloaded from Sentinel2 into 10m (band 5 and band 8a), but it turned out many errors, especially "resample/projection is not a function".  I used the codes that I learned from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOcQnxph4dw, but still it didn't work.

Here is my script, it would be really great if someone can help me out from the beginning.

Plus, even if I filter the cloud with certain percentage, the result map still seems super cloudy, is there anyway that I can select better imagery?

```js
var s2large2016 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 1)) 
.filterBounds(geometry)
.select([
      // Make this list whichever bands you want to view or analyze
      'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A'
    ]);


Map.addLayer(s2large2016,{min:0,max:8000, gamma:2, bands:['B4','B3','B2']},'sentinel2large2016');
Map.centerObject(s2large2016);


// Finding resolution of a band / image
var b5 = s2large2016.select('B5');
var resolution = b5.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B5 Resolution');

var b8a = s2large2016.select('B8A');
var resolution = b8a.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B8A Resolution');


// Resampling B5 to 10m/Pixel
var resampled_b5 = b5.resample('bilinear')
                  .reproject({
                    crs: b5.projection(),
                    scale:10
                  });

var resolution = resampled_b5.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B5 Resampled Resolution');                  

Map.addLayer(b8,{},'B8');
Map.addLayer(resampled_b8,{},'Resampled B8');             

Map.addLayer(b5,{},'B5');
Map.addLayer(resampled_b5,{},'Resampled B5');
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are applying the `.projection()` method, which can be applied to an `ee.Image`, to an `ee.ImageCollection`. In your code, `s2large2016` is an `ee.ImageCollection`. You need to think what do you want to do to reduce `s2large2016` to an `ee.Image`. For example, you might want to apply an `ee.Reducer.mean`.

Here's the updated working code, where we simply get the `.first()` image from the image collection to test the rest of the code:

```js
var s2large2016 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 1)) 
.filterBounds(geometry)
.select([
      // Make this list whichever bands you want to view or analyze
      'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A'
    ])
.first(); // Here you probably want to do something else than just
// take the first image.. maybe you want to apply a reducer
// to get an ee.Image instead of ee.ImageCollection.

Map.addLayer(s2large2016,{min:0,max:8000, gamma:2, bands:['B4','B3','B2']},'sentinel2large2016');
Map.centerObject(geometry,11);

// Finding resolution of a band / image
var b5 = s2large2016.select('B5');
var resolution = b5.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B5 Resolution');

var b8a = s2large2016.select('B8A');
var resolution = b8a.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B8A Resolution');


// Resampling B5 to 10m/Pixel
var resampled_b5 = b5.resample('bilinear')
                  .reproject({
                    crs: b5.projection(),
                    scale:10
                  });

var resolution = resampled_b5.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B5 Resampled Resolution');                  

Map.addLayer(b5,{min:0,max:1000},'B5');
Map.addLayer(resampled_b5,{min:0,max:1000},'Resampled B5');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3d33e96771b80d60bbf542b60ca34dc5

Comment: Hello Oliver, thank you for your answer! It helps me a lot!

However, I would like to know that the purpose of ".first" only means testing the codes instead of only choosing one image from the imagecollection. Should I mosaic the imagecollection first before resampling?  The "ee.Reducer.mean" as I know is aggregating the data,  but what I saw from the result you provided, the whole Image is already been merged, can you explain me more about this?

Comment: Besides, I only know the output images are captured based on my region of interest, but how to know all the information about every image? 

The last question would be, can I reselect the images from Sentinel2 or optimize the result so that the outcome imagcollection is not that cloudy?

Comment: .first() is literally just giving you the first image in the image collection. When you added `s2large2016` as an image collection to the map using Map.addLayer(), it automatically mosaicked the images for you to display it on the map, but the object `s2large2016` remained as an image collection. If you want to mosaic the images to be used with your other operations, then replace the `.first()` by `.mosaic()`.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-mosaic explains multiple ways of reducing a collection to a single image.